# Need to trigger event for all the rows on select all checkbox in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have written something `onSelectRow` now when I select particular record this code in `OnselectRow` event get executed even if I trigger `setSelection` method it excutes. but when I select select All checkbox all the rows get selected without excuting `OnselectRow`

What I need is when I select top Checkbox I need to execute `onSelectRow` event for every record of the grid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hey buddy All you need is to rewrite all the in loop of all the records in `onSelectAll` event ane you can trigger it from there. for example

```
     onSelectRow: function(id,status){
          ... some code for this id ...
     },onSelectAll:function(id,status){

         for(i=0;i<id.length;i++){
               .... same some code for id[i] .....
         }

     }
```

and That's It.
You are welcome :)

Comment: Perfecto Thanks Abbignail.

Answer (score 1):

There are exist `onSelectAll` callback which should be used to handle `click` event on "select All" chechbox in the header of multiselect column.